# Unable to call sub-function when it is used with self but works fine without self

Tags: python, tkinter, methods, nested-function

I have a function, `start_round()` that initializes the round and creates temporary round variables. Then I have a nested function, `rd_animate()` that does the animation. Now when I make this `rd_animate()` function a method, the code does not work. When I do not include self, it works fine. Can anyone explain why this happens?

## Code

### Without `self`

```py
def start_round(self):
    def rd_animate():
        #--::Animation::--#
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
        self.PF_ani_lbl["text"] = "ROUND {}".format(self.round_no)
        self.after(500)
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place_forget()

    print("start_round")
    #--::Creation of round dictionary::--#
    self.round = {}

    #--::Animation::--#
    threading.Timer(0.05, rd_animate).start()
```

### With `self`

```py
def start_round(self):
    def rd_animate(self):
        #--::Animation::--#
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
        self.PF_ani_lbl["text"] = "ROUND {}".format(self.round_no)
        self.after(500)
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place_forget()

    print("start_round")
    #--::Creation of round dictionary::--#
    self.round = {}

    #--::Animation::--#
    threading.Timer(0.05, self.rd_animate).start()
```

## Error

It gives an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\Desktop\Pratham\My Coding\MY APPS\RPS Multiplayer Game\root-recreated.py", line 348, in <lambda>
    command = lambda: self.start_match(retrieve()))
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\Desktop\Pratham\My Coding\MY APPS\RPS Multiplayer Game\root-recreated.py", line 613, in start_match
    super().start_match(username, "Computer", match_settings)
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\Desktop\Pratham\My Coding\MY APPS\RPS Multiplayer Game\root-recreated.py", line 533, in start_match
    self.start_round()
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\Desktop\Pratham\My Coding\MY APPS\RPS Multiplayer Game\root-recreated.py", line 616, in start_round
    super().start_round()
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\Desktop\Pratham\My Coding\MY APPS\RPS Multiplayer Game\root-recreated.py", line 445, in start_round
    self.rd_animate()
  File "C:\Users\raghavendra\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2354, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'rd_animate'
```

I want to have it with `self` since it would be nice

Comment: It is better to post the code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The posted code is the working one.  You need to post the *not working* one and the full error traceback if any.

Comment: I have posted the working and not working code along with the error with full traceback. Hope you can figure out the problem now.

Comment: Just adding `self` argument does not change the nested function to class method.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer with a workaround (if possible)?

Comment: Just move the function to outside `start_round()`, a class method cannot be a nested function.

Comment: Okay, but as I said I don't want it to be a class method but only a nested function. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248839/discussion-between-pycoder-and-acw1668).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are just objects. As the error says, `self` is an instance of the tkinter app. It won't have your `rd_animate` function unless you set it.

```
self.rd_animate = rd_animate
threading.Timer(0.05, self.rd_animate).start()
```

You'll also want to create a partial function to actually pass the app instance into the parameter of the animate function. That way, the lines within the function won't throw an error saying 1 parameter is expected, but got zero

---

Alternatively, not really clear why you're nesting things since the above code would be similar to this since `self` refers to the enclosing class, only for functions definitely *directly* in the class body

```
class App(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master) 
    self.round_no = 0
    self.PF_ani_lbl =... 

  def rd_animate(self):
    #--::Animation::--#
    self.PF_ani_lbl.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
    self.PF_ani_lbl["text"] = "ROUND {}".format(self.round_no)
    self.after(500)
    self.PF_ani_lbl.place_forget()

  def start_round(self):
    threading.Timer(0.05, self.rd_animate).start()
```

You can make `rd_animate` "private" function by adding two underscores in front like `def __rd_animate`

Comment: I wanted nested things since it would be kind of messy to include functions that would be called by only 1 specific method into the main body. I also knew that I could make private functions. But it helped your answer helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All tkinter parts of the code need to run in the same thread so running rd_animate in a separate thread is probably causing the problem.  Replace the `threading` code with `self.after`.  `after` returns immediately so `.place_remove` runs before the label is `placed`.  Put the remove in a separate function and use that as a callback in `.after`

```
def start_round(self):

    def remove_label():
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place_forget()
        
    def rd_animate():
        #--::Animation::--#
        self.PF_ani_lbl.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
        self.PF_ani_lbl["text"] = "ROUND {}".format(self.round_no)
        self.after(500, remove_label )

    print("start_round")
    #--::Creation of round dictionary::--#
    self.round = {}

    #--::Animation::--#
    self.after( 50, rd_animate)
```

Comment: Well, I don't even need to change the `threading.Timer()` to `self.after` or move the `ani_lbl.place_forget()` into another function to make the code work. My code in the question works perfectly fine. But with your code if I add `self` as a parameter, it does not work. I want an explanation why does it not work if I add self, and if there is a workaround.